# React Native flatlist rendering multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am creating an application that interacts with spotify. A part of my app is a FlatList screen displaying a list of songs and song controls.

[Image of Playlist Song Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtEq6.png)

Inside each component that is rendered, I added a `Rendering` log.

```
function SongListItem({ data, onTap }) {
  console.log('Rendering ', data.track.name)
  // Renders Text, 64px x 64px Image, and Button that emits `onTap`.
}
```

When I open a playlist, I get the list rerendering *6* times!!! See the `useEffect` hooks of the component for the top half of the log.

```
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.321]  LOG      Already loading...
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.371]  LOG      Songs to fetch set to 100
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.372]  LOG      Loading has been set to true
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.372]  LOG      Loading page # 0
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.372]  LOG      song length now 0
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.378]  LOG      getSongsOfPlaylist 0
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.580]  LOG      32 new songs
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      32 Total songs
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      Rendering  **first 10 songs** // Condensed log
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.814]  LOG      Already loading...
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.832]  LOG      song length now 32
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      Rendering  **first 10 songs** // Condensed log
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.944]  LOG      Already loading...
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.999]  LOG      Songs to fetch set to 0
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      Rendering  **first 10 songs** // Condensed log
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:31.143]  LOG      Loading has been set to false
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      Rendering  **11 songs** // Condensed log
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      Rendering  **22 songs** // Condensed log
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      Rendering  **31 songs** // Condensed log
[Sun Mar 07 2021 13:28:30.581]  LOG      Rendering  **32 songs** // Condensed log
```

Here is code for the component. I have excluded code for the playing of music (The `onTap` callback.)

```
function PlaylistDetailScreen({ route, navigation, authentication, ...props }) {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
  const [songsToFetch, setSongsToFetch] = useState(100)
  const { playlistID } = route.params
  const pop = () => navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(1))

  const getSongsOfPlaylist = async (aToken, aPlaylist, aPage, aLimit) => {
    console.log('getSongsOfPlaylist', aPage)
    const response = await authHandler.get(aToken, aPlaylist, aPage, aLimit)
    if (response) {
      console.log(response.data.items.length, 'new songs')
      console.log(response.data.total, 'Total songs')
      let remainingSongs =
        response.data.total - songs.length - response.data.items.length
      setSongs([...songs, ...response.data.items])
      setSongsToFetch(Math.min(100, remainingSongs))
    } else {
      console.error('There was a problem fetching data')
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Songs to fetch set to', songsToFetch)
  }, [songsToFetch])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Loading has been set to', loading)
  }, [loading])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Loading page #', page)
    updateReduxWithValidAccessToken(authentication)
      .then((token) => getSongsOfPlaylist(token, playlistID, page))
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [page])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('song length now', songs.length)
  }, [songs])

  function renderListItem({ item }) {
    return <SongListItem data={item} onTap={onTap} /> // onTap handles the playback of music
  }

  function loadMore() {
    console.log('loadMore')
    if (!loading && songsToFetch > 1) {
      setPage(page + 1)
    }
  }

  function renderFooter() {
    if (!loading) {
      return <MyText> END OF DATA </MyText>
    } else {
      console.log('Already loading...')
      return <MyText> LOADING... </MyText>
    }
  }

  return (
    <ContainerView>
      <MySongList
        data={songs}
        renderItem={renderListItem}
        keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        onEndReached={loadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1} // They must scroll 90% through data to load
      />
    </ContainerView>
  )
}

async function updateReduxWithValidAccessToken({
  accessToken,
  accessExpiration,
  refreshToken,
}) {
  // ...
  return validToken;
}
```

Why is my component rerendering so many times, and how can I fix it?

#### EDIT with full code snippets.

SongListItem

```
const IconButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  margin-right: 5px;
`
const MyIcon = styled(Icon)`
  font-size: 25px;
`

function PressableIcon({ name, onPress }) {
  return (
    <IconButton onPress={onPress}>
      <MyIcon name={name} />
    </IconButton>
  )
}

function PlayButtonEmitter({ disabled, onEmit }) {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)

  if (!disabled) {
    return (
      <PressableIcon
        name={disabled ? '' : isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play'}
        onPress={() => {
          onEmit(!isPlaying)
          setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)
        }}
      />
    )
  }
  return null
}
function SongListItem({ data, onTap }) {
  console.log('Rendering ', data.track.name)
  const soundURL = data.track.preview_url
  return (
    <ListItemContainer>
      <LeftSideGroup>
        <AlbumCover source={{ uri: data.track.album.images[2].url }} />
        <SongTitle>{data.track.name || 'NULL'}</SongTitle>
      </LeftSideGroup>
      <PlayButtonEmitter
        disabled={soundURL === null}
        onEmit={(play) => onTap(play ? soundURL : null)}
      />
    </ListItemContainer>
  )
}
export default SongListItem
```

PlaylistDetail

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  ContainerView,
  MyText,
  MyButton,
  MySongList,
  OverlaidSelectButton,
  SeparatorLine,
} from './styles'

import SongListItem from '_components/SongListItem'
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  setAccessToken,
  setRefreshToken,
} from '_redux/features/authenticationSlice'
import authHandler from '_utils/authenticationHandler'
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player'

import styled from 'styled-components/native'

const ContainerView = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
`

const MyText = styled.Text``

const MyButton = styled.TouchableOpacity``

const MySongList = styled.FlatList``

const SeparatorLine = styled.View`
  width: 75%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
`

const OverlaidSelectButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
`



function PlaylistDetailScreen({ route, navigation, authentication, ...props }) {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
  const [songsToFetch, setSongsToFetch] = useState(100)
  let currentlyPlaying = null
  const { playlistID } = route.params
  const pop = () => navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(1))

  const getSongsOfPlaylist = async (aToken, aPlaylist, aPage, aLimit) => {
    console.log('getSongsOfPlaylist', aPage)
    const response = await authHandler.get(
      `/playlists/${aPlaylist}/tracks`,
      aToken,
      {
        offset: 100 * aPage,
        limit: aLimit,
        fields:
          'total,items(track(preview_url, id, name, duration_ms, artists, album(!available_markets)))',
      },
    )
    if (response) {
      console.log(response.data.items.length, 'new songs')
      console.log(response.data.total, 'Total songs')
      let remainingSongs =
        response.data.total - songs.length - response.data.items.length
      if (remainingSongs >= 0) {
        setSongs([...songs, ...response.data.items])
      } else {
        remainingSongs = 0
      }
      setSongsToFetch(Math.min(100, remainingSongs))
    } else {
      console.error('There was a problem fetching data')
    }
  }
  async function onTap(song) {
    if (song !== null) {
      if (currentlyPlaying !== song) {
        await TrackPlayer.reset()
        await TrackPlayer.add({
          url: song,
        })
      }
      await TrackPlayer.play()
      currentlyPlaying = song
    } else {
      await TrackPlayer.pause()
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (songs.length === 0) {
      TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(() => {
        console.debug('Player Initialized.')
      })
    }
  }, [songs])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Songs to fetch set to', songsToFetch)
  }, [songsToFetch])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Loading has been set to', loading)
  }, [loading])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Loading page #', page)
    updateReduxWithValidAccessToken(authentication)
      .then((token) => getSongsOfPlaylist(token, playlistID, page))
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [page])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('song length now', songs.length)
  }, [songs])

  function renderListItem({ item }) {
    return <SongListItem data={item} onTap={onTap} />
  }

  function loadMore() {
    console.log('loadMore')
    if (!loading && songsToFetch > 1) {
      setPage(page + 1)
    }
  }

  function renderFooter() {
    if (!loading) {
      return <MyText> END OF DATA </MyText>
    } else {
      console.log('Already loading...')
      return <MyText> LOADING... </MyText>
    }
  }

  function renderSeparator() {
    return <SeparatorLine />
  }
  return (
    <ContainerView>
      <MyText> PlaylistID: {playlistID} </MyText>
      <MyButton onPress={pop}>
        <MyText>Go back</MyText>
      </MyButton>
      <MySongList
        data={songs}
        renderItem={renderListItem}
        keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        onEndReached={loadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1} // They must scroll 90% through data to load
      />
      <OverlaidSelectButton
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('PlaylistSettings')}>
        <MyText> Select </MyText>
      </OverlaidSelectButton>
    </ContainerView>
  )
}

async function updateReduxWithValidAccessToken({
  accessToken,
  accessExpiration,
  refreshToken,
}) {
  if (accessToken === null || new Date() > new Date(accessExpiration)) {
    console.log('Access Token is Invalid, Refreshing...')
    console.log('refreshToken=', refreshToken)
    const response = await authHandler.refreshLogin(refreshToken)
    accessToken = response.accessToken
    setAccessToken({
      accessToken,
      accessExpiration: response.accessTokenExpirationDate,
    })
    setRefreshToken({
      refreshToken: response.refreshToken,
    })
  }
  return accessToken
}

// enough boilerplate ;)
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    authentication: state.authentication,
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setAccessToken,
  setRefreshToken,
}
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(PlaylistDetailScreen)
```

Comment: Please let me know if information about the `MusicPlayer` or `SongListItem` component is needed.

Comment: Are you logging in `SongListItem` in a `useEffect`? Can you include `SongListItem` component code in your question as it seems to be the relevant code you have some issue with?

Comment: @DrewReese sure, just added. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I see, try also logging `console.log('Rendering ', data.track.name)` in an `useEffect` so it is logging only when `data.track.name` updates and the component is rendered to the DOM (versus when the component is rendered for diffing purposes during reconciliation).

Comment: @DrewReese here is a pastebin of the output with the `useEffect` hook. https://pastebin.com/vupNVMk8. It looks nearly identical.

Comment: @DrewReese Do you need anything else?

Comment: What you had first shared in the pastebin looked a little different, but didn't seem abnormal. I just realized that you haven't shown how you are rendering the `FlatList` component. Can you also include the `MySongList` component so we can see what it is doing with passed props? Keep in mind that any state updates in `PlaylistDetailScreen` will trigger a rerender, including children.

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited the question to include full details of every file.

Comment: By every file, I mean `SongListItem`, and `PlaylistDetailScreen`